# How to apply conditions on multiple columns and display an error message in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as below.

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|  w|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  4|  4|  4|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I want to apply a condition where if any column value is greater than zero then display an error message saying your count is more than zero for this column

```
e.g. if df.x >0:
        print("your count is more than zero for column x ")
```

similarly the code should display the message for all the columns where value is more than zero.

Please help in writing the code using pyspark in python as I am very new to this platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each column, filter using the condition you specified, and check to see if the size of the resulting DataFrame is greater than 0.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

for c in df.columns:
    if df.where(col(c) > 0).count() > 0:
        print("your count is more than zero for column {col}".format(col=c))
```

For the example that you provided, the output would be:

```
your count is more than zero for column y
your count is more than zero for column z
your count is more than zero for column w
```